How to add CA-Certificate to appwrite in docker compose?
I am running an appwrite server on a company network and I need to add a ca certificate for web requests.
The specific problem is, that appwrite uses serverless functions which are build by appwrite. This build fails with the following error
Got TLS error trying to find package pubspec at https://pub.dev.
My interpretation of the error tells me that the certificate is not used for this request and therefore is missing in the docker image.
I saw some solutions with modifying the Dockerfile directly, but since the dockerfile is not managed by myself but by the appwrite team I am searching for a solution on the docker compose file.
So far I've mounted the cert path via volume in the docker compose file, but that does not seem to solve the problem.
Example appwrite docker compose file:
x-logging: &x-logging
  logging:
    driver: 'json-file'
    options:
      max-file: '5'
      max-size: '10m'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:2.11
    container_name: appwrite-traefik
    <<: *x-logging
    command:
      - --providers.file.directory=/storage/config
      - --providers.file.watch=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false
      - --providers.docker.constraints=Label(`traefik.constraint-label-stack`,`appwrite`)
      - --entrypoints.appwrite_web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.appwrite_websecure.address=:443
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - appwrite-config:/storage/config:ro
      - appwrite-certificates:/storage/certificates:ro
    depends_on:
      - appwrite
    networks:
      - gateway
      - appwrite

  appwrite:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    container_name: appwrite
    <<: *x-logging
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.constraint-label-stack=appwrite
      - traefik.docker.network=appwrite
      - traefik.http.services.appwrite_api.loadbalancer.server.port=80
      #http
      - traefik.http.routers.appwrite_api_http.entrypoints=appwrite_web
      - traefik.http.routers.appwrite_api_http.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)
      - traefik.http.routers.appwrite_api_http.service=appwrite_api
      # https
      - traefik.http.routers.appwrite_api_https.entrypoints=appwrite_websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.appwrite_api_https.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)
      - traefik.http.routers.appwrite_api_https.service=appwrite_api
      - traefik.http.routers.appwrite_api_https.tls=true
    volumes:
      - appwrite-uploads:/storage/uploads:rw
      - appwrite-cache:/storage/cache:rw
      - appwrite-config:/storage/config:rw
      - appwrite-certificates:/storage/certificates:rw
      - appwrite-functions:/storage/functions:rw
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - redis
#      - clamav
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_LOCALE
      - _APP_CONSOLE_WHITELIST_ROOT
      - _APP_CONSOLE_WHITELIST_EMAILS
      - _APP_CONSOLE_WHITELIST_IPS
      - _APP_CONSOLE_HOSTNAMES
      - _APP_SYSTEM_EMAIL_NAME
      - _APP_SYSTEM_EMAIL_ADDRESS
      - _APP_SYSTEM_SECURITY_EMAIL_ADDRESS
      - _APP_SYSTEM_RESPONSE_FORMAT
      - _APP_OPTIONS_ABUSE
      - _APP_OPTIONS_ROUTER_PROTECTION
      - _APP_OPTIONS_FORCE_HTTPS
      - _APP_OPTIONS_FUNCTIONS_FORCE_HTTPS
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_DOMAIN
      - _APP_DOMAIN_TARGET
      - _APP_DOMAIN_FUNCTIONS
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_SMTP_HOST
      - _APP_SMTP_PORT
      - _APP_SMTP_SECURE
      - _APP_SMTP_USERNAME
      - _APP_SMTP_PASSWORD
      - _APP_USAGE_STATS
      - _APP_STORAGE_LIMIT
      - _APP_STORAGE_PREVIEW_LIMIT
      - _APP_STORAGE_ANTIVIRUS
      - _APP_STORAGE_ANTIVIRUS_HOST
      - _APP_STORAGE_ANTIVIRUS_PORT
      - _APP_STORAGE_DEVICE
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_BUCKET
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_SIZE_LIMIT
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_TIMEOUT
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_BUILD_TIMEOUT
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_CPUS
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_MEMORY
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_RUNTIMES
      - _APP_EXECUTOR_SECRET
      - _APP_EXECUTOR_HOST
      - _APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER
      - _APP_LOGGING_CONFIG
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_INTERVAL
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_DELAY
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_RETENTION_EXECUTION
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_RETENTION_CACHE
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_RETENTION_ABUSE
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_RETENTION_AUDIT
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_RETENTION_USAGE_HOURLY
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_RETENTION_SCHEDULES
      - _APP_SMS_PROVIDER
      - _APP_SMS_FROM
      - _APP_GRAPHQL_MAX_BATCH_SIZE
      - _APP_GRAPHQL_MAX_COMPLEXITY
      - _APP_GRAPHQL_MAX_DEPTH
      - _APP_VCS_GITHUB_APP_NAME
      - _APP_VCS_GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY
      - _APP_VCS_GITHUB_APP_ID
      - _APP_VCS_GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET
      - _APP_VCS_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET
      - _APP_VCS_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID
      - _APP_MIGRATIONS_FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID
      - _APP_MIGRATIONS_FIREBASE_CLIENT_SECRET
      - _APP_ASSISTANT_OPENAI_API_KEY

  appwrite-realtime:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: realtime
    container_name: appwrite-realtime
    <<: *x-logging
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.constraint-label-stack=appwrite"
      - "traefik.docker.network=appwrite"
      - "traefik.http.services.appwrite_realtime.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      #ws
      - traefik.http.routers.appwrite_realtime_ws.entrypoints=appwrite_web
      - traefik.http.routers.appwrite_realtime_ws.rule=PathPrefix(`/v1/realtime`)
      - traefik.http.routers.appwrite_realtime_ws.service=appwrite_realtime
      # wss
      - traefik.http.routers.appwrite_realtime_wss.entrypoints=appwrite_websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.appwrite_realtime_wss.rule=PathPrefix(`/v1/realtime`)
      - traefik.http.routers.appwrite_realtime_wss.service=appwrite_realtime
      - traefik.http.routers.appwrite_realtime_wss.tls=true
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - redis
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPTIONS_ABUSE
      - _APP_OPTIONS_ROUTER_PROTECTION
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_USAGE_STATS
      - _APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER
      - _APP_LOGGING_CONFIG

  appwrite-worker-audits:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: worker-audits
    <<: *x-logging
    container_name: appwrite-worker-audits
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mariadb
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER
      - _APP_LOGGING_CONFIG

  appwrite-worker-webhooks:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: worker-webhooks
    <<: *x-logging
    container_name: appwrite-worker-webhooks
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mariadb
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_SYSTEM_SECURITY_EMAIL_ADDRESS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER
      - _APP_LOGGING_CONFIG

  appwrite-worker-deletes:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: worker-deletes
    <<: *x-logging
    container_name: appwrite-worker-deletes
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mariadb
    volumes:
      - appwrite-uploads:/storage/uploads:rw
      - appwrite-cache:/storage/cache:rw
      - appwrite-functions:/storage/functions:rw
      - appwrite-builds:/storage/builds:rw
      - appwrite-certificates:/storage/certificates:rw
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_STORAGE_DEVICE
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_BUCKET
      - _APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER
      - _APP_LOGGING_CONFIG
      - _APP_EXECUTOR_SECRET
      - _APP_EXECUTOR_HOST

  appwrite-worker-databases:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: worker-databases
    <<: *x-logging
    container_name: appwrite-worker-databases
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mariadb
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER
      - _APP_LOGGING_CONFIG

  appwrite-worker-builds:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: worker-builds
    <<: *x-logging
    container_name: appwrite-worker-builds
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mariadb
    volumes:
      - appwrite-functions:/storage/functions:rw
      - appwrite-builds:/storage/builds:rw
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_EXECUTOR_SECRET
      - _APP_EXECUTOR_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER
      - _APP_LOGGING_CONFIG
      - _APP_VCS_GITHUB_APP_NAME
      - _APP_VCS_GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY
      - _APP_VCS_GITHUB_APP_ID
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_TIMEOUT
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_BUILD_TIMEOUT
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_CPUS
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_MEMORY
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_SIZE_LIMIT
      - _APP_OPTIONS_FORCE_HTTPS
      - _APP_OPTIONS_FUNCTIONS_FORCE_HTTPS
      - _APP_DOMAIN
      - _APP_STORAGE_DEVICE
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_BUCKET

  appwrite-worker-certificates:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: worker-certificates
    <<: *x-logging
    container_name: appwrite-worker-certificates
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mariadb
    volumes:
      - appwrite-config:/storage/config:rw
      - appwrite-certificates:/storage/certificates:rw
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_DOMAIN
      - _APP_DOMAIN_TARGET
      - _APP_DOMAIN_FUNCTIONS
      - _APP_SYSTEM_SECURITY_EMAIL_ADDRESS
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER
      - _APP_LOGGING_CONFIG

  appwrite-worker-functions:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: worker-functions
    <<: *x-logging
    container_name: appwrite-worker-functions
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mariadb
      - openruntimes-executor
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_TIMEOUT
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_BUILD_TIMEOUT
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_CPUS
      - _APP_FUNCTIONS_MEMORY
      - _APP_EXECUTOR_SECRET
      - _APP_EXECUTOR_HOST
      - _APP_USAGE_STATS
      - _APP_DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME
      - _APP_DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
      - _APP_LOGGING_CONFIG
      - _APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER

  appwrite-worker-mails:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: worker-mails
    <<: *x-logging
    container_name: appwrite-worker-mails
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_SYSTEM_EMAIL_NAME
      - _APP_SYSTEM_EMAIL_ADDRESS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_SMTP_HOST
      - _APP_SMTP_PORT
      - _APP_SMTP_SECURE
      - _APP_SMTP_USERNAME
      - _APP_SMTP_PASSWORD
      - _APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER
      - _APP_LOGGING_CONFIG

  appwrite-worker-messaging:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: worker-messaging
    <<: *x-logging
    container_name: appwrite-worker-messaging
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    volumes:
      - appwrite-uploads:/storage/uploads:rw
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER
      - _APP_LOGGING_CONFIG
      - _APP_SMS_FROM
      - _APP_SMS_PROVIDER
      - _APP_STORAGE_DEVICE
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_LINODE_BUCKET
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_ACCESS_KEY
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_SECRET
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_REGION
      - _APP_STORAGE_WASABI_BUCKET

  appwrite-worker-migrations:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: worker-migrations
    <<: *x-logging
    container_name: appwrite-worker-migrations
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_DOMAIN
      - _APP_DOMAIN_TARGET
      - _APP_SYSTEM_SECURITY_EMAIL_ADDRESS
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER
      - _APP_LOGGING_CONFIG
      - _APP_MIGRATIONS_FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID
      - _APP_MIGRATIONS_FIREBASE_CLIENT_SECRET

  appwrite-task-maintenance:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: maintenance
    <<: *x-logging
    container_name: appwrite-task-maintenance
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_DOMAIN
      - _APP_DOMAIN_TARGET
      - _APP_DOMAIN_FUNCTIONS
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_INTERVAL
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_RETENTION_EXECUTION
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_RETENTION_CACHE
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_RETENTION_ABUSE
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_RETENTION_AUDIT
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_RETENTION_USAGE_HOURLY
      - _APP_MAINTENANCE_RETENTION_SCHEDULES

  appwrite-worker-usage:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: worker-usage
    container_name: appwrite-worker-usage
    <<: *x-logging
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mariadb
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_USAGE_STATS
      - _APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER
      - _APP_LOGGING_CONFIG
      - _APP_USAGE_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL

  appwrite-worker-usage-dump:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: worker-usage-dump
    <<: *x-logging
    container_name: appwrite-worker-usage-dump
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mariadb
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_USAGE_STATS
      - _APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER
      - _APP_LOGGING_CONFIG
      - _APP_USAGE_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL

  appwrite-task-scheduler-functions:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: schedule-functions
    container_name: appwrite-task-scheduler-functions
    <<: *x-logging
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - redis
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS

  appwrite-task-scheduler-messages:
    image: appwrite/appwrite:1.5.7
    entrypoint: schedule-messages
    container_name: appwrite-task-scheduler-messages
    <<: *x-logging
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - redis
    environment:
      - _APP_ENV
      - _APP_WORKER_PER_CORE
      - _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1
      - _APP_REDIS_HOST
      - _APP_REDIS_PORT
      - _APP_REDIS_USER
      - _APP_REDIS_PASS
      - _APP_DB_HOST
      - _APP_DB_PORT
      - _APP_DB_SCHEMA
      - _APP_DB_USER
      - _APP_DB_PASS

  appwrite-assistant:
    image: appwrite/assistant:0.4.0
    container_name: appwrite-assistant
    <<: *x-logging
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    environment:
      - _APP_ASSISTANT_OPENAI_API_KEY

  openruntimes-executor:
    container_name: openruntimes-executor
    hostname: exc1
    <<: *x-logging
    restart: unless-stopped
    stop_signal: SIGINT
    image: openruntimes/executor:0.5.5
    networks:
      - appwrite
      - runtimes
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - appwrite-builds:/storage/builds:rw
      - appwrite-functions:/storage/functions:rw
      # Host mount nessessary to share files between executor and runtimes.
      # It's not possible to share mount file between 2 containers without host mount (copying is too slow)
      - /tmp:/tmp:rw
    environment:
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_INACTIVE_TRESHOLD=$_APP_FUNCTIONS_INACTIVE_THRESHOLD
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_MAINTENANCE_INTERVAL=$_APP_FUNCTIONS_MAINTENANCE_INTERVAL
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_NETWORK=$_APP_FUNCTIONS_RUNTIMES_NETWORK
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME=$_APP_DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD=$_APP_DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_ENV=$_APP_ENV
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_RUNTIMES=$_APP_FUNCTIONS_RUNTIMES
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_SECRET=$_APP_EXECUTOR_SECRET
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_LOGGING_PROVIDER=$_APP_LOGGING_PROVIDER
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_LOGGING_CONFIG=$_APP_LOGGING_CONFIG
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_DEVICE=$_APP_STORAGE_DEVICE
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_S3_ACCESS_KEY=$_APP_STORAGE_S3_ACCESS_KEY
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_S3_SECRET=$_APP_STORAGE_S3_SECRET
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_S3_REGION=$_APP_STORAGE_S3_REGION
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET=$_APP_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_ACCESS_KEY=$_APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_ACCESS_KEY
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_SECRET=$_APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_SECRET
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_REGION=$_APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_REGION
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_BUCKET=$_APP_STORAGE_DO_SPACES_BUCKET
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_ACCESS_KEY=$_APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_ACCESS_KEY
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_SECRET=$_APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_SECRET
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_REGION=$_APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_REGION
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_BUCKET=$_APP_STORAGE_BACKBLAZE_BUCKET
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_LINODE_ACCESS_KEY=$_APP_STORAGE_LINODE_ACCESS_KEY
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_LINODE_SECRET=$_APP_STORAGE_LINODE_SECRET
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_LINODE_REGION=$_APP_STORAGE_LINODE_REGION
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_LINODE_BUCKET=$_APP_STORAGE_LINODE_BUCKET
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_WASABI_ACCESS_KEY=$_APP_STORAGE_WASABI_ACCESS_KEY
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_WASABI_SECRET=$_APP_STORAGE_WASABI_SECRET
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_WASABI_REGION=$_APP_STORAGE_WASABI_REGION
      - OPR_EXECUTOR_STORAGE_WASABI_BUCKET=$_APP_STORAGE_WASABI_BUCKET

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.11 # fix issues when upgrading using: mysql_upgrade -u root -p
    container_name: appwrite-mariadb
    <<: *x-logging
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - appwrite
    volumes:
      - appwrite-mariadb:/var/lib/mysql:rw
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${_APP_DB_ROOT_PASS}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${_APP_DB_SCHEMA}
      - MYSQL_USER=${_APP_DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${_APP_DB_PASS}
      - MARIADB_AUTO_UPGRADE=1
    command: 'mysqld --innodb-flush-method=fsync'

  redis:
    image: redis:7.2.4-alpine
    container_name: appwrite-redis
    <<: *x-logging
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: >
      redis-server
      --maxmemory            512mb
      --maxmemory-policy     allkeys-lru
      --maxmemory-samples    5
    networks:
      - appwrite
    volumes:
      - appwrite-redis:/data:rw

  # clamav:
  #   image: appwrite/clamav:1.2.0
  #   container_name: appwrite-clamav
  #   restart: unless-stopped
  #   networks:
  #     - appwrite
  #   volumes:
  #     - appwrite-uploads:/storage/uploads

networks:
  gateway:
    name: gateway
  appwrite:
    name: appwrite
  runtimes:
    name: runtimes

volumes:
  appwrite-mariadb:
  appwrite-redis:
  appwrite-cache:
  appwrite-uploads:
  appwrite-certificates:
  appwrite-functions:
  appwrite-builds:
  appwrite-config:


Thanks in advance for your input! Cheers!
